# fail2ban find a apache regex

Tags: regex, apache2

I am trying to setup fail2ban and fail with the regex... in my apache logs I have lines like this

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Sep/2013:12:41:21 +0200] "GET /shop/index.php?do=/blog/add HTTP/1.1" 301 566 "http://www.tld.com/shop/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)"
```

All of these entries have in common the "?do=" which is not valid at all (so no regular pages will be affected)
I tried to catch it with a regex like

```
failregex = <HOST> - - * "GET *\?do\=*
```

but it gives no match.
After several hours of searchig I am lost. Anyone can help me with the regex?

Answer (score 1):

Missing another dot:

```
failregex = <HOST> - - .* "GET *\?do\=.*
                       ^              ^
```

Played with it in the online regexp tester:

http://regex101.com/r/jQ7wQ9/1

Answer (score 0):

the way you have it, the "*" is searching for string of spaces and then checking got "?do". I think you want:

```
failregex = <HOST> - - .* "GET *\?do\=* 
                       ^
```